# Swift for macOS: How to call functions across Window Controllers?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I am working on a simple ToDo app as a project to teach myself Swift.  I am branching out from the Udemy tutorials I have followed so far, trying to add new features to the apps built in-class.

The main window contains a Vertical Split View Controller.

The left View Controller is a table which displays a list of ToDo items by title.  It contains a function `getToDoItems()` which updates the table when called.

Right View Controller shows ToDo item details.  There is a "Delete" button on the right View Controller which removes the item from Core Data, and calls `getToDoItems()` from the left View Controller.  (So I'm able to call functions across View Controllers within the same window)

New items are added via a popup window.  The popup window correctly appears, accepts input, saves entries to Core Data, and closes then window when I click add.  However, the call to `getToDoItems()` contained in the left View Controller in the Main Window doesn't go through.

At the top of the PopupWindowVC, I have:

```
var toDoListVC : ToDoListViewController? = nil
```

and at the end of the Add ToDo function I have

```
toDoListVC?.getToDoItems()
```

`getToDoItems()` contains a print statement that indicates when it is successfully called, and it doesn't run when I click the button.  I can tell the data is saving correctly, because deleting an item (which calls the `getToDoItems()`) will make new entries appear, as will stopping and restarting the app.

I figure that I may need to somehow link the two Window Controllers (or do something else entirely) but I haven't found any guidance or tutorials on how to do address this type of problem.  Any suggestions or links to good tutorials are welcome!

## *** Edit ***

Still learning StackOverflow...hopefully this is how I do this

That tutorial is from 2012, but I found this newer one here:

[link](https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3)

I was reading along and got to the line:

```
let quote = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
```

I figured out that NSTableViews don't have indexPaths, but NSCollectionViews do, so I set out to learn about NSCollectionViews.  I've been doing well right up until the point I try to dynamically number the Items in my CollectionView.

My question about NSCollectionViews is at [How to use NSCollectionView indexPath to number items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440482/how-to-use-nscollectionview-indexpath-to-number-items)

Comment: A better way is to handle this via core data, either if you're using NSFetchedResultsController and let the left vc be the delegate or more manually by observing notifications from core date in the left vc. Both options will mean core data tells you there have been changes and you act on them and you don't need to have a strong coupling between the pop up and the left vc

Comment: Thanks Joakim - I read up on NSFetchedResultsController and I see the value in structuring my app to use it.  I've looked through several examples online yesterday and today and haven't found a tutorial I can understand about how to implement this.  Please let me know if you are aware of such a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: Here is one on [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)